# reactjs react-router : Unable to get property 'route' of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a reactjs beginner and I am trying react-router.
Here is my code.

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactRouter from 'react-router';

var Route = ReactRouter.Route
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

import App from './App.jsx';
import Home from './Home.jsx';
import About from './About.jsx';
import Contact from './Contact.jsx';



ReactDOM.render((
<Router history = {browserHistory}>
  <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
     <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
     <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
     <Route path = "about" component = {About} />
     <Route path = "contact" component = {Contact} />
  </Route>
</Router>


), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Error code: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'route' of undefined or null reference. Thanks

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: react-router - 4.4.1

Comment: never heard of that version, are you sure?

Comment: I type npm react-router -v on cmd and this is appeared

Comment: {
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My react first app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^0.9.5",
    "webpack": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "Snow",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: above is package.json

Comment: IndexRoute does not exist on react-router v4

Comment: I suggest you to use the version ^3.0.0 until we get a better documentation of the version 4.0.0. You should not use nested components this way, also, the IndexRoute component does not exists anymore.